# Marie Simulator Multiplication of fractions

Tags: marie

I have a task to use Marie Simulator to calculate the area of a circle
requiring its radius

I know that in Marie Language there is no multiplication operator so we use multiplication by adding numbers several times so If I wanted to multiply 2*3 I could write it down like 3+3 or 2+2+2

but when using the area of a circle there is pi which is 3.14 I can't imagine how could I get it so can anyone give me the algorithm or code for that ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MARIE does not have floating point support.

So, should refer to your course work or ask your instructors what to do, as it is not obvious.

It is, of course, possible to do floating point in software, but the complexity is extraordinary, so unlikely to be what the're looking for.

You could use fixed point arithmetic, fractions, or decimal.

Here's one solution that might be appropriate: multiply one of the numbers (having decimal places) by some fixed constant factor, do the arithmetic, then interpret answers accordingly.  For example, let's use 100 as the factor, so 3.14 is represented by 314.  Let's say `r` is 9, so we can square that (9x9=81), then multiply 81 x 314 = 25434.  Now we know that value is 100x too large, so the real answer is 254.34.  (You can choose to ignore the .34, or, round it, then ignore.  254 is still more accurate than 243 which we would get from 9x9x3.)

[Fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) multiplies all numbers by the constant (usually a power of 2, so that the binary point is in the same bit position).  Additions are relatively straightforward, but multiplications need to interpret results by factoring in (or out) that *both* sources are in scaled, meaning the answer is doubly scaled.

If you need to measure radius also with decimal digits, e.g. 9.5, then you could scale both 9.5 and 3.14 by 100.  Then we need 950x950, and multiply by 314.  The answer will be 100x100x100 too large, so 1000000x too large.  With this approach, 16 bits that MARIE offers will overflow, so you would need to use at least 32-bit arithmetic (not trivial on 16-bit machine).

You can use two different scaling factors, e.g. 9.5 as 95 and 3.14 as 314.  Take 95x95x314, is 10000x too large, so interpret the answer accordingly.  Still this will overflow MARIE's 16-bits

Fractions would maintain both a numerator and denominator for all numbers.  So, 3.14 could be 314/100, and 9.5 could be 95/10 — and simplified 157/50 and 19/2.  To add you have to find a common denominator, convert, then sum numerators.  To multiply you multiply both numerators and denominators: numerator = 19x19x157, denominator = 2x2x50.  Just fits in 16-bit unsigned arithmetic, but still overflows 16-bit signed arithmetic..

And finally binary coded decimal is more like a string format, where numbers are stored one decimal digit per byte or per nibble (packed decimal).  Algorithms for addition and subtraction need to account for variable length inputs.

Big integer forms also use similar to binary coded decimal but compose much larger elements instead of single decimal digits.

All of these approaches require some thought, and the more limitations you want to remove, the more work required.  So, I'd suggest to go back to your course to find what they really want.

Comment: Dear Mr. Erik, 

first of all, I'd like to express my great gratitude for your detailed great answer which illuminates lots of things. Secondly, If your time allows, could you please tell me can MARIE accept floats in simple way like I want to add 0.50 + 0.50 , what would its code look like ? 

thanks in advance

Comment: There is no explicit support for floating point, only integer.  You would have to simulate something more complex using integer capabilities; one of the approaches like I mention above, or something else, even.